# "Error parsing the type of column" Redshift Spectrum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a use case for spectrum using files a large amount of json files from s3. I started by crawling the data using a Glue crawler to create a data catalog. Then with that catalog I created an external schema to reference the Glue database so I could access the catalog. Now I am able to do select statements on root level strings, and it works Ex:

```
select t.id from glue_db.test t
```

The problem is that when I do a select statement on struct objects I am getting this error "Error parsing the type of column 't.actor.name'". Here is an example select (id is a string within the actor struct):

```
select t.actor.name from glue_db.test t
```

What am I missing? I have also tried to convert the json to parquet, and am running into the same problems trying to query the nested data.

Here is the glue table def:

[image]

Here is the actor struct:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The attributes that contain nested values need to be specified in the FROM clause so Redshift knows how to access them. Also need to confirm that catalog Glue generated specifies the tables correctly.

```
select a.id 
from glue_db.test t, t.actor a
```

Please see this tutorial for help on querying nested data with Redshift Spectrum. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data-sqlextensions.html

Comment: I am getting that same parse error. I am updating the question, and adding the glue table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and after getting in contact with AWS Support I found out that the backslash ( \ ) character in the field name causes this exact exception, in your case the fields `bb\user.id` and `bb\user.externalId`.

So for me editing the schema and removing temporary the field containing " \ " or renaming the field removing the backslash (e.g. `bbuser.id`) resolved the issue.

[image]

Credits @[hyruma92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5002698/hyruma92)